# How can I change hover back-ground-color of ul list items

Tags: html-lists

Spent HOURs without success.  Remodeling current ecommerce site to be responsive. Construction site: www.abundant-yarns.com. Image below shows backgrounds I want to change.  When "Our Services" is clicked, I want the gray active state behind "Our Services" to be the tan color.  When hovering over the menu items, I want the blue hover color to be green.  Please assist this this task.  Thanks

Comment: There is no image "below".

Answer (score 0):

```
.navbar-nav>.open>a, .navbar-nav>.open>a:hover, .navbar-nav>.open>a:focus {
   color: #555;
   background-color: red;
}
```

That will allow you to change the gray background on click.

```
.dropdown-menu>li>a:hover, .dropdown-menu>li>a:focus {
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
    background-color:  black;
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear,left 0,left 100%,from(#428bca),to(#357ebd));
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,#428bca,0%,#357ebd,100%);
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top,#428bca 0,#357ebd 100%);
    background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom,#428bca 0,#357ebd 100%);
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#ff428bca',endColorstr='#ff357ebd',GradientType=0);
    }
```

This will allow you to change the blue hover to whatever you want by adjusting the above rules (namely: background-color).

See if this helps.

*I just put random colors in there so you can see the difference.*  As well, you're overriding Bootstrap core CSS here so remember it will apply globally.

Comment: And so fast.  I was expecting to wait hours or days. How does one express appreciation on this forum?  Both solutions work well.  I'm not yet flashy enough for gradient li items so I modified your second suggestion to:.dropdown-menu>li>a:hover, .dropdown-menu>li>a:focus {
 text-decoration: none;
 background-image: none;
        background-color: #6c9d31;
        }

Comment: You can express appreciation by accepting my answer as being the correct answer... ;-)  Let me see that green check!!! LOL

Comment: BTW... all that "background-image" is doing is making a gradient, it's built into BootStraps core CSS that's why I included it.